# macro copy and past value and send

Tags: vba, excel

Good day everyone,
I have a request I could  not find anywhere.. I have an excel file that needs to be filled in by our sales team. Once filled in they send it to me.. In the file I have a field where Windows ID is automatically added (=username()). But as soon I receive the doc and open it, my ID is popping up.
Is there a possibility to get a "button" or "icon" where sales team could "clic" and action behind would be => copy/past the value of username so I have the name of the sales that completed the doc and "send" to a specific email address?
Thanks a lot for your help
Wishing you all a very nice day
Pierre

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please note that SO is for developers to ask other developers for help when they get stuck with code they have written. SO is not a 'please code this for me' site. I highly recommend spending more time searching SO and Google for help on getting started with this problem since there are plenty of resources out there if you take the time to look.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I understand and will search on other website and google

Comment: @CarHibou if you show the code you used to `Windows ID is automatically added (=username())` then we could give you a better answer...

Comment: @Xabier, thanks a lot. In fact in my file, I have a cell with formula (=username()) and in the visual basic (module 4) I have Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function  ==> I would need to add to this, a "copy/past value" so next person that will open the file will see the original windows ID + an automatic sent to a specific email address. Do you thinik it is possible?

Comment: @CarHibou please have a look at my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which cell you have the formula in, you can copy and paste it as values before closing the file, so that it doesn't get updated when you go ahead an open it again, the example below will search for the formula and then paste the contents of the cell as values, put this code under ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'edit the name of worksheet above as required
    Dim rng As Range
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="username()", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range(rng.Address).Copy
        ws.Range(rng.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier, thanks a lot it is perfect, i really appreciate your help. shuold i close this ticket?